# Collect list of attributes with groovy and jsonslurper into single list

Tags: json, groovy

What's the best way to collect a list of attributes from a JSON hierarchy?  Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsontxt = '''
{
    "lvl1": [
        {
            "lvl2": [
                {
                  "lvl3": [
                                {
                                    "a1": false,
                                    "a2": {
                                        "a2b1": false,
                                        "a2b2": false
                                    },
                                    "a3": "wantvalue1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "a1": false,
                                    "a2": {
                                        "a2b1": false,
                                        "a2b2": false
                                    },
                                    "a3": "wantvalue2"
                                }
                        ],
                },
            ],
        }
    ]
}
'''

def jsresult = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsontxt)
def mytry = jsresult.lvl1.lvl2.lvl3.collect{it.a3} // [[[wantvalue1, wantvalue2]]]

assert ["wantvalue1","wantvalue2"] == mytry
```

Apologies the input is not as clean as it could be but I didn't want to lose my situation.

What I want is a basic list without the additional empty lists.  I know there must be a really cool way to do this but I'm not groovy enough for it. . . help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty close. Try [flatten()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#flatten%28%29).

Try `jsresult.lvl1.lvl2.lvl3.collect{it.a3}.flatten()` or `myTry.flatten()`

Comment: Or: `jsresult.lvl1.lvl2.collectMany { it.lvl3.collectMany { it.a3 } }`

Comment: Is there any way to do this with built-in functions without knowing the depth?

Comment: @TWiStErRob You can use recursion. I don't think there is a built-in function but I may be wrong w.r.t newest version of Groovy. I will have to check.